# How to invoke generators from code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, generator

I wrote my own generator, from console its launched like this

```
rails generate ead_document TechnicalOpinion --document_type_id=1
```

It creates model and migration. I want to execute generator from my controller without using ruby system command. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Solution appears to be pretty simple:

This code in controller

```ruby
Rails::Generators.invoke("ead_document", [@document_type.table_name.classify, "--document_type_id=#{@document_type.id}"])
```

is the same as this in console

```sh
rails generate ead_document TechnicalOpinion --document_type_id=1
```

In case you want to use it outside a controller, you may also want to require it explicitely:

```ruby
require 'rails/generators'
```

Comment: Could you please open a new question about the API thing rather than answering with a question? That way we have the questions & answers searchable.

Comment: I blogged about it with a different perspective: I wrote an article about it: https://medium.com/@kdiogenes/programmable-generators-on-rails-fe04f08033bf

Comment: This solution has a big problem, the options array does not get populated from the args provided. I am still trying to figure out why. I tried setting ARGV.replace(args) still no luck. any suggestions?