# new scaffold generator with some default files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am making a new rails scaffold generator to replace the default one, most of the files remain the same, only some are different. So how do I invoke some of the default scaffold files within my generator?
Also, is there a way I can checkout the source code of the original scaffold generator?

Answer (score 0):

The source code is in the [railties section of the project on github](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/0ccdeeb6b589b486f9ffdfb56cbbf901ec955d88/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails). To gain access to the scaffold templates, I would just [invoke the actual scaffold generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081478/how-to-invoke-generators-from-code) and then gsub the files if you need to make changes.